# Using #include <stdbool.h> in C

Tags: c, arrays, debugging, netbeans, boolean

I have no clue why this is happening. Has anyone encountered this? I'm using Netbeans 8.2 and the program is running in debug mode.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define N 100

int main() {
    //all lockers are closed
    bool lockers[N + 1] = {false};

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Variables window in debug mode]

As you can see Netbeans is saying that some indexes hold what appear to be int values and the one highlighted is even true when I have declared all values to be false.

Comment: Please don't have code only available in an image.  Include it in the question.  And avoid the debugger images too when possible.

Comment: Which is the current line when the debugger displays the bogus values?  Could it be before the initialization is executed so the contents are indeterminate?  Until you get to the `return 0;`, the values in `lockers` are not really determinate.

Comment: How else can I show what the problem is besides explaining it in text?

Comment: Also, please show us complete code, not part of it. What is `N`? Why is there `numberOfStudents`?

Comment: Ah that is correct. The program was not finished setting the values of each element to false since it had not reached return 0;

Comment: For future reference, please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  This is now OK, though, as an example, adding `printf("locker[8] = %d\n", locker[8]);` would have displayed 0 (false) instead of 252.  It would also have given you a stopping point before the `return` statement.

Comment: Maybe you are simply viewing the value in the debugger before the line `bool lockers[N + 1]= {false};` has evenbeen executed... At any rate, nobody will be able to reproduce the problem with the information given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Booleans are an arithmetic type and, as such, should be initialised as if they were statics when you don't provide an explicity value in the initialiser.

This is detailed (paraphrased) in (for example) `C11 6.7.9 Initialization`:

> 21/ If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.
>
> 10/ If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly and if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero.

In terms of *properly* checking, make a temporary change to your code as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define N 100

int main() {
    //all lockers are closed
    bool lockers[N + 1]= {false};

    for (int i = 0; i <= N; ++i)
        if (lockers[i])
            printf("%d is the wrong value\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

You *shouldn't* get any output at all and, if that's the case, either the NetBeans debugger is wrong or you're using it wrong :-)

Comment: *if that's the case, either the NetBeans debugger is wrong or you're using it wrong* A bit late here, but the third possibility is the initialization was optimized out since the `lockers` array in the original code was never accessed.

Comment: @Andrew, that *is* a good point, at least for the original code since it may well be that the "as if" rule is being followed and the compiler has figured out it's not used.